# table of content order is different as appear on page

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my thesis with LaTeX. I am facing a problem with roman numbers. Numbers that appeared on pages are correct like `i, ii, iii,...` But arrangement in the table of content is different. It is like

> declaration................ i
>   languange certificate  .....i

```
\pagenumbering{roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Declaration}
i am ....
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Language Correctness Certificate}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Language Correctness Certificate}
i am bla bla.....
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright Statement}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Copyright Statement}
i am blabla....
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
i am.....
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*%{Dedication}
bnn.....
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Abstract}
....
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\cleardoublepage
\noindent
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage
\noindent
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\cleardoublepage
\noindent
\listoftables
\clearpage
```

Comment: Off topic: You add the last page of ToC, LoT and LoF to the Table of Contents. With a standard class you could use package `tocbibind` to get the desired ToC entres. With a KOMA-Script class you could use class option `listof=totoc` and macro `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}`.

Comment: it worked.it worked. but i dnt want to show dedication heading. when i hide this heading dedication by using % then it shows some error. what should i do? \cleardoublepage \chapter*%{Dedication} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication} \noindent \begin{center} \Large \textit{ To my family who have always encouraged me} \end{center} \cleardoublepage \chapter*{Abstract} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

Comment: Do not comment the argument of `\chapter`! With a standard class you can use `\chapter*{}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}` or if the vertical space should be removed too: `\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}`. Bud maybe its better to ask a new question with an updated MWE.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Is it twosided and with option `openany` or `openright`?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter        
\addchap{Declaration}% No number but into TOC
    i am ....

\addchap{Language Correctness Certificate}
    i am bla bla.....

\mainmatter 
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked. but i dnt want to show dedication heading. when i hide this heading dedication by using % then it shows some error.  what should i do?
\cleardoublepage                                            \chapter*%{Dedication}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\noindent      \begin{center}
       \Large   \textit{ To my family who have always encouraged me}  
               \end{center}        

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

Comment: `addchap{Dedication}`

Comment: it shows same error. it is not working

Comment: @Ayesha: With a KOMA-Script class you can use `\addchap[Dedication]{}` or if the vertical space should be removed too: `\cleardoublepage\addchaptertocentry{}{Dedication}`.

Answer (score 1):

Have `\addcontentsline` after `\chapter*` - otherwise it will show the pagenumber from the previous content

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
i am ....

\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Language Correctness Certificate}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Language Correctness Certificate}
i am bla bla.....

\cleardoublepage
\noindent
\tableofcontents


\end{document}
```

Comment: This will be ok in the `MWE` given but will fail if fx `hyperref` is added later... Herbert's solution below using KOMA's `\addchap` will be saver...

Comment: @AndiW There is no mention of hyperref in the question - even if hyperref is used a simple `\phantomsection` solved the problem. It is much more likely that one of the standard classes is used and not an obscure koma class.

Comment: Yep, but I did not say your solution does not work. I just wanted give the OP a hint that your solution (once more: does work) but might be limited. (no discussion about koma being obscure...) So sorry if you felt offended which was not my intention...